# HTML ordered list - specific order

Tags: html, html-lists

in HTML/CSS, is it possible to have my ordered list in the following format?

```
  o. Item 1
  i. Item 2
 ii. Item 3
iii. Item 4
```

More generally, is it possible to create my own format for ordered lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could use the `<ol>` tag for roman numerals simply by adding a type.

```
<ol type="i">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

This HTML spits out:

```
i. Coffee
ii. Tea
iii. Milk
```

More information can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_type.asp

For you `o` being the first position item, start your count at the second item and prepend the first one using Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: The only problem with that is that he wants an 'o' to represent 0. Ordered lists with the type of Roman Numerals doesn't include o.

Comment: Hm, I guess you could prepend a list item using Javascript or jQuery to get that effect, but you can't do it natively in HTML.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking maybe iterating through a list, but that's OOP.

Comment: @AndrewL well, that's what JS is for! haha. I mean, you could write some crazy code to to generate all of your lists that way if its a common thing in your app, but I wouldn't :s.

Comment: I wouldn't either, but considering this (generation a small list), then it could be a possible way.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is an arbitrarily styled first element. All subsequent list items should then have a number text which is one lower than their natural ordering would suggest. Correct?

Thus, your HTML List is simply:

```
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

The following CSS does the actual magic. However (minor drawback), I believe you need to set the width of the `:before` pseudo-element explicitly in order to resemble the appearance of an "ordinary" list.

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  counter-increment: strangecounter;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(strangecounter, lower-roman) ". ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

ol :first-child {
  counter-reset: strangecounter -1;
}

ol :first-child:before {
  content: "o. ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @morido. This was exactly what i wanted to do! I just have a last question. I used txt-align inside li:before, but know I need to add a right margin in the li:before. Do you have an idea of the value that I should use in order to make it llok like to other lists?

Comment: I've ameded my answer to make the number texts align to the right. You need to use a `padding-right` or `margin-right` value in order to get that gap you requested.